# How to split rows into two columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'probegene' : ['1431492_at Lipn', '1448678_at Fam118a','1452580_a_at Mrpl21'],
                   '(5)foo.ID.LN.x2' : [130, 150,173],
                   '(5)foo.ID.LN.x1' : [20.3, 25.3,3.1]})
```

That looks like this:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   (5)foo.ID.LN.x1  (5)foo.ID.LN.x2            probegene
0             20.3              130      1431492_at Lipn
1             25.3              150   1448678_at Fam118a
2              3.1              173  1452580_a_at Mrpl21
```

What I want to do is to split the rows in `probegene` into two columns, resulting in:

```
probe           gene    (5)foo.ID.LN.x1  (5)foo.ID.LN.x2            
1431492_at      Lipn           20.3              130      
1448678_at      Fam118a        25.3              150   
1452580_a_at    Mrpl21          3.1              173
```

How can I achieve that?

I'm stuck with this:

```
df['probegene'].str.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if this is the best approach, but if you `.apply(pd.Series)` to the result of the `split`, you get a correctly-indexed frame.  After that you can join:

```
>>> new_cols = df.pop("probegene").str.split().apply(pd.Series)
>>> new_cols.columns = ["probe","gene"]
>>> df = df.join(new_cols)
>>> df
   (5)foo.ID.LN.x1  (5)foo.ID.LN.x2         probe     gene
0             20.3              130    1431492_at     Lipn
1             25.3              150    1448678_at  Fam118a
2              3.1              173  1452580_a_at   Mrpl21
```

The reason I'm not sure if this is the best way is because `apply` tends to be slow.  Something like

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df["probegene"].str.split().tolist(), index=df.index)
```

would probably be faster, in case this is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Single line solution

```
df['probe'], df['gene'] = zip(*df['probegene'].str.split())
```