# Split and encode one column into n colums with 0 and 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DF` with 3000000 lines. `df[A]` is a combination with a random `len`  and with numbers from 1 to 10 splitted by a `','`

| A |
| --- |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 7,1 |
| 9 |
| 1,2,7 |

I would like to have that

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Thx

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090573/how-to-split-rows-into-two-columns-in-pandas

Comment: Unfortunately no because the len of the values to unpack is not a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0Something like this (for the sake of time, I create a simplified dataframe, but the principle should be the same):

```
 data={"A": ["7",
"8",
"7,1",
"9",
"1,2,7"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

    
       A
0      7
1      8
2    7,1
3      9
4  1,2,7
```

And then encode:

```
df_encode = df.A.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

print(df_encode)

```
   1  2  7  8  9
0  0  0  1  0  0
1  0  0  0  1  0
2  1  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  1  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: The answer is not the same as the output in the question. There are no values bigger than 1.

Comment: I think you have to change the level from 1 to 0.
    df_encode = df.A.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=1)

Comment: That worked perfectly with level=0. Thanks you so much !

Comment: well spot. thanks for constructive comments. I did it quickly. Kr

Comment: @ErwanBOURHIS, cool that it helps. don't hesitate to accept this as answer if that is the case :). Kr.

Comment: @antoine Nice answer..You can skip the `split`  + `stack` part here. directly use `str.get_dummies` and pass the `sep` parameter as `,` like `df['A'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for output with columns `1` to `10`. Firstly, split by `,` and explode the array to get the coordinates which have to be 1

```
temp_df = df['A'].str.split(',').to_frame().explode('A').astype(int).reset_index()
temp_df

  index A
0   0   7
1   1   8
2   2   7
3   2   1
4   3   9
5   4   1
6   4   2
7   4   7
```

Using directly numpy arrays as they are easy for updating multiple cooridnates. Update the above cooridnates with 1.

```
a = np.zeros((len(df), 10))
a[temp_df['index'], temp_df['A']-1] = 1 # -1 because the columns are 1 to 10 instead of 0 to 9
a
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])

pd.DataFrame(a, columns=list(range(1,11))).astype(int)
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
4   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```